# Bigcommerce PHP API link Brand to Product

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I can create and update brands no problem with the Bigcommerce PHP API, but I am unable to figure out how to link a brand to the product using the API.

Has anyone had experience with this?

**Update**

I need to update this:

```
<brand>
<link rel="resource" href="https://my-store.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/brands/0.xml">/brands/0</link>
</brand>
```

/brands/0 is looking for brand ID. I already know how to get that ID, I just need to be able to populate it and am not sure how.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some specific code with us? Otherwise, this question will likely be flagged as too broad/unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

There is a field of the product called brand_id, and you populate that with the brand's id generated by Bigcommerce.

i.e. `'brand_id' => 401,`

where 401 is the brand's id